# Latex: The packages ngerman and dcolumn don't work together

Tags: dcolumn

The following example won't compile (pdflatex). You can test that it compiles WITHOUT the package ngerman. But the the quotation marks are not correct. I don't know anything about the interior of packages, but the interference of these two packages seems very strange to me.
Here is my example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, german]{scrartcl}%Koma-scriprt!
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\begin{document}

Nun probieren wir die "`Anführungszeichen"' hier.

%\end{document}

\begin{tabular}{D{,}{,}{-1}p{2 cm}D{,}{,}{-1}p{2 cm}D{,}{,}{-1}}
31,5 &  & 42,39 &  & 312,1\\
9,123 &  & 17,2 &  & 99,53\\
58,9 &  & 210,15 &  & 201,4\\
64,27&  & 29,314 &  & 32,39\\
50,41 &  & 151,3 &  & 26,1\\
\hline
154,203 &  & 410,354 &  & 671,52
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: The package `ngerman` is unsupported and was last updated in 1998. It's been superseded by the `babel` package -- with language option `ngerman` -- for a decade or more. Happily, your code compiles *just fine* if I replace `\usepackage{ngerman}` with `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`.

Comment: Thanks, with \usepackage[ngerman]{babel} everything works fine!